# Is there a ticker application available?

Tags: software-recommendation

By ticker application, i mean a ticker application, which will display RSS feeds as well as my own RSS feed and i can place this feed anywhere on the desktop.

Comment: [...]By ticker application, i mean a ticker application[...] lulz, fo course you do, I remember there was a Feed Indicator *though* i don't know if it still works with 11.10. You could also be using a Widget to show the feeds or set up Conky too.

Comment: Try adobe air(closed source) from usc
1000s of .air ticker apps are available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [tickr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tickr.1.html) ?

It is in the repositories and puts a scrolling news ticker across your desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [snackr](http://snackr.net/) (open source). But you'll have to install Adobe Air though.
[image: Screenshot of Snackr]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As of right now, Adobe Air for Linux is discontinued. Also, to make your answer even better, you can upload a screenshot of snackr. For more on that, please read this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Just did that. I guess I didn't have the privilege initially. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Continued development of Adobe Air is discontinued, but version 2.6 works with Linux and is still available [link](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/853/cpsid_85304.html).